# Convert colored scanned image to black-white image

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, imagemagick, artificial-intelligence

I have scanned images like this where the background color is not necessarily consistent. When I use an ImageMagick command like this, it will apply a fixed threshold, which is not good for images without a consistent background.

```
convert in.jpg -threshold 35% -type bilevel -monochrome -compress LZW out.pdf
```

Can anybody provide a robust way to generate the corresponding monochrome image maintaining all the texts?

I think the best method probably should be based on deep learning. But DL may take too many resources to run. Non-DL methods are also welcome if it can render reasonably good results.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can improve that using -lat function in Imagemagick as follows:

Input:

[image]

```
convert coahuila.jpg -colorspace gray -negate -lat 50x50+10% -negate result.jpg
```

[image]

Note: I suggest saving as PNG or TIFF to avoid extra JPG compression.  I only saved as JPG since this forum has size restrictions.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the spots near the bottom/right edge during the process?

Comment: Not with just -lat.  You can try adjusting the arguments especially the 10%. That will reduce them, but may reduce your text readability as well.  You could try some morphology to merge the text rows into one large region and then get the largest connected component's bounding box and use that to crop your text away from the margins and then add a new margin of pure white.

Comment: Can imagemagick do this? Or it will need to be done with a different tool?

Comment: Imagemagick can do what I proposed. I will try to give you an example with your image later today.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another Imagemagick 6 approach using division normalization and thresholding. Then some morphology to connect the rows of text.  Then followed by connected components processing to find the largest black connected region. From that we extract the bounding box and use its dimension to crop the normalized image and thresholded image and pad back out with white to the size of the original image.

Input:

[image]

```
dims=$(convert coahuila.jpg -format "%wx%h" info:)
bbox=$(convert coahuila.jpg \
-colorspace gray \
\( +clone -blur 0x20 \) \
+swap \
-compose divide -composite \
-threshold 70% \
-type bilevel \
+write coahuila_div.png \
-morphology open rectangle:1x55 \
-morphology close rectangle:3x1 \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:keep-top=1 \
-connected-components 8 coahuila_ccl.png | \
grep "gray(0)" | awk '{print $2}')
convert coahuila_lat.png \
-crop $bbox +repage \
-background white -gravity center -extent $dims \
coahuila_processed.png
```

Division Normalized and Thresholded Image:

[image]

Morphology Connected Image:

[image]

Final Result:

[image]

Note if using Imagemagick 7, change convert to magick and also you can replace -threshold 70% to -auto-threshold otsu.

**ADDITION**

This version pads the bounding box to avoid cropping too close to the text.

```
dims=$(convert coahuila.jpg -format "%wx%h" info:)
bbox=$(convert coahuila.jpg \
-colorspace gray \
\( +clone -blur 0x20 \) \
+swap \
-compose divide -composite \
-threshold 70% \
-type bilevel \
+write coahuila_div.png \
-morphology open rectangle:1x55 \
-morphology close rectangle:3x1 \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:keep-top=1 \
-connected-components 8 coahuila_ccl.png | \
grep "gray(0)" | awk '{print $2}' | tr "x" "+" )

pad=10
ww=$(echo $bbox | cut -d+ -f1)
hh=$(echo $bbox | cut -d+ -f2)
xo=$(echo $bbox | cut -d+ -f3)
yo=$(echo $bbox | cut -d+ -f4)
ww=$((2*pad+ww))
hh=$((2*pad+hh))
xo=$((xo-pad))
yo=$((yo-pad))

convert coahuila_div.png \
-crop ${ww}x${hh}+${xo}+${yo} +repage \
-background white -gravity center -extent $dims \
coahuila_processed.png
```

Result:

[image]

Adjust the pad as desired.

*I make no claim that this is a universal solution. Some adjustment will be needed if the text is larger or the spacing is larger between lines, etc.*

Comment: It seems the top-left is missing one character ("in" -> "n", the top-right is missing a little (the page number "5").

Comment: We just need to buffer the bounding box a little.

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer above.

Answer (score -1):

You obtain a good result with adaptive thresholding (for instance size 43, offset 28 but this setting is not critical).

[image]

Comment: Could you show me the exact command that you used?

Comment: @user1424739: 
 
 Operator::Binarize(43, -28, Image0, Binarized0, true);

Comment: What command is it for? ImageMagick? Or for some other tools?

Comment: @user1424739: mViz, VISION fOr VISION.